# PostgreSQL query selecting items between a number range, but the column is given as strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named ISO and a column bet that is a string type. They are all numbers btw, real ones.

how do I select all bets between number x and number y for example?

Comment: Why store numeric data in a string column? Alter column data type!

Answer (score 2):

Storing a number as a string is a bad idea.  But it is easy enough to convert the values:

```
select iso.*
from iso
where (iso.bet::int) between x and y;
```